# Open iTerm2 from bash script & Run commands

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

***Summary***

I'm trying to write a script to automatically launch my development server in iTerm2 from VS Code.

When I open my VS Code project, I want my bash script to:

1. open iTerm2 (
2. run cd .. && cd OtherFolder
3. run npm start (so my node server will start)

***Problem***

I know how to open iTerm2 but I can't figure out how to make the bash script I wrote then run the commands from #2 and #3 in iTerm2 because I need to run the bash script from the VS Code terminal and then open iTerm2.

Comment: You put the commands in a file and execute the file.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more?  I already created my bash script and am running it in from the VS Code terminal.  Once the bash script opens iTerm, how would I tell the original bash script to execute commands in iTerm?

Comment: Why do you want to execute the commands in another terminal?  Just leave out this open iTerm2 stuff and just execute your cd's commands an npm start.

Comment: I’m developing a React Native app and a node.js server.  I want the server to launch in a separate window from VS Code.  My goal is to open my React Native project folder in VS code and run a bash script that starts the iOS & Android simulators—very easy—and then launch a separate terminal for my server

Comment: You'd be better off using `screen` or `tmux` to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

The following bash script uses Applescript to launch iTerm.  You can modify it to use iTerm2 instead of iTerm.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Open new iTerm window from the command line
#
# Usage:
#     iterm                   Opens the current directory in a new iTerm window
#     iterm [PATH]            Open PATH in a new iTerm window
#     iterm [CMD]             Open a new iTerm window and execute CMD
#     iterm [PATH] [CMD] ...  You can prob'ly guess
#
# Example:
#     iterm ~/Code/HelloWorld ./setup.sh
#
# References:
#     iTerm AppleScript Examples:
#     https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/wikis/Applescript
# 
# Credit:
#     Inspired by tab.bash by @bobthecow
#     link: https://gist.github.com/bobthecow/757788
#

# OSX only
[ `uname -s` != "Darwin" ] && return

function iterm () {
    local cmd=""
    local wd="$PWD"
    local args="$@"

    if [ -d "$1" ]; then
        wd="$1"
        args="${@:2}"
    fi

    if [ -n "$args" ]; then
        # echo $args
        cmd="; $args"
    fi

    osascript &>/dev/null <<EOF
        tell application "iTerm"
            activate
            set term to (make new terminal)
            tell term
                launch session "Default Session"
                tell the last session
                    delay 1
                    write text "cd $wd$cmd"
                end
            end
        end tell
EOF
}
iterm $@
```

Comment: I found this and tried it but isn't this the code for an AppleScript as opposed to a bash script?

Comment: Yes, the above code uses AppleScript. In their official site, they recommend using AppleScript.

Comment: For iTerm2 it would look like this: ```tell application "iTerm2"
  create window with default profile 
  tell current session of current window
   delay 1
   write text "cd $wd$cmd"
  end tell
 end tell``` - sorry for the missing linebreaks - SO commenting doesn't allow them.

Comment: iTerm's Applescript support is now deprecated. The supported alternative is to use the Python API. See https://iterm2.com/python-api/examples/launch_and_run.html.

Comment: Applescript won't go away—it's in maintenance mode. Use it if it solves your problem. When you run in to a wall, switch to Python.

Answer (score 1):

This [small program](https://github.com/knrz/iterm-workspace) I built for myself do what you're looking for.  It takes a configuration file like this:

```json
{
  "tabs": [
    {
      "commands": ["cd /to/other/folder", "cd /to/project && npm start"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My version, based in part on @ubuntudroid's comment:

```
function dovt
{
    osascript <<EOF
    tell application "iTerm2"
         create window with default profile
         tell current session of current window
              delay 1
              write text "cd $PWD"
              write text "$@"
          end tell
    end tell
EOF
}
```

Comment: this worked inside a bash script. thankyou